# The Set-Cookie header is not working in Safari

Tags: cookies, setcookie

I want to make use of Set-Cookie header to set some cookies.

Set-Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.572388820.1578481097; Max-Age=3500; Domain=example.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 18 Jan 2020 11:57:47 GMT; Secure; SameSite=Strict

The request is made from example.com to subdomain.example.com. So, I would say the problem with cross-domain is solved, since we are on the same "main" domain.

Still, even after the successfull set-cookie response, the cookie is not set. It even deletes the cookie if I had set the same cookie with document.cookie.

Any idea why this is not working?

Best regards,
Jos